# TypeError: "'int' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, error-handling

I'm trying to assign group numbers to products for items that have been out of stock multiple days in a row. Whenever there is a break in consecutive days out of stock, I need to assign a new group number. I've worked out the SQL so that if an item number/day combination is consecutive, it is assigned a 1, else 0 (group number iterates at 0's).

I've written the following simple function so that the variable group_num iterates +1 if the counter is 0, otherwise returns group_num as is:

```
def add_groups():
    group_num=1

    for c in df['counter']:
        if c==0:
            group_num+=1
        else:
            group_num+=0

    return (group_num)

    df.apply(add_groups(),axis=1)
```

I keep getting the error `'int' object is not callable, 'occurred at index 0'` and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please format your code so that we can help you better.

Comment: You're passing the *result* of calling `add_groups()` to `df.apply`, equivalent to `df.apply(1, ...)`. You probably want to remove the `()` at least there so you're passing *the function*.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if you've reused a name in two different places, such as a method name and a function name.When these two names are repeated, the program will call an Int by default, but the Int object has no invocation to speak of, so the error is broken, so to fix it, either change the variable name or change the method name.I hope this is helpful.